# Using a PSDataCollection with BeginInvoke in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to process output from a pipeline within my PowerShell script. Right now the only way that I see the output is when I've issued the `EndInvoke` method for the pipeline, but since some of my calls can be long-running and can have a lot of output I'd like to be able to display the output as the process runs.

It looks like I might be able to do this by passing in input and output parameters to the `BeginInvoke` method, but I can't seem to get the syntax correct. Any suggestions? An example of what I'm trying is below:

```
$scriptBlock = {param([int]$pauseTime = 10); Write-Output "Test"; Start-Sleep -Seconds $pauseTime; Write-Output "Test 2"}

# Create objects and set stuff up
$initialSessionState = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState]::CreateDefault()
$runspacepool = [Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, 4, $initialSessionState, $Host)
$runspacepool.Open()
$pipeline = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($scriptBlock).AddParameter("pauseTime", 30)
$pipeline.RunspacePool = $runspacepool

# These two lines are not correct
$inputStream = New-Object [System.Management.Automation]
$outputStream = New-Object [System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection]

$async = $pipeline.BeginInvoke($inputStream, $outputStream)

# Do something with the $outputStream here???

$pipeline.EndInvoke($async)

# Clean-up code    
$pipeline.Dispose()
$async = $null
$pipeline = $null
if ($runspacepool -ne $null) {$runspacepool.Close()}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish (it looks overcomplicated too me for the simple purpose of processing the output from a script) but with this small modification of your PowerShell Script at least you'll get an ouput:

```
` $scriptBlock = {
    param([int]$pauseTime = 1)
    Write-Output "Test 1"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $pauseTime
    Write-Output "Test 2"
   }

    # Create objects and set stuff up
    $initialSessionState = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState]::CreateDefault()
    $runspacepool = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, 4, $initialSessionState, $Host)
    $runspacepool.Open()
    $pipeline = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($scriptBlock).AddParameter("pauseTime", 5)
    $pipeline.RunspacePool = $runspacepool

    $outputStream = New-Object -Typename  System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[PSObject]

    $async = $pipeline.BeginInvoke()
    1..10 | Foreach { "Im waiting..."; Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500 }

    $outputStream = $pipeline.EndInvoke($async)

    # Clean-up code    
    $pipeline.Dispose()
    $async = $null
    $pipeline = $null
    if ($runspacepool -ne $null) {$runspacepool.Close()}

    $outputStream
`
```